# modalviewcontroller pushes view controller that would like to dismiss

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

So I've created a modalviewcontroller that has a navigation bar like so...

```
PurchaseSelectVendor *selectVendor = [[PurchaseSelectVendor alloc] initWithNibName:@"PurchaseSelectVendor" bundle:nil ];
        UINavigationController *modalNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:selectVendor];
        [selectVendor release];
        [self presentModalViewController:modalNavController animated:YES];
        [modalNavController release];
```

The modal view will then push another view controller. (We'll call it view 2)

```
PurchaseNewItems *newItemsController = [[PurchaseNewItems alloc] initWithNibName:@"PurchaseNewItems" bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:newItemsController animated:YES];
[newItemsController release];
```

view 2 has a navigation bar with a done button. When the user taps the done button I want it to dismiss to the view that presented the modal view in the first place.

Everything I try just dismisses view 2 back to the madalview that presented it.

What is the proper way to accomplish this?

Comment: What code did you try? for me a simple [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] should work.

Comment: Doing that just pops the controller back to selectVendor

Comment: and [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]?

Comment: [self.parentviewcontroller.presentingviewcontroller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] was what I needed. However now when it goes to the original view (a list of purchase orders) the view is blank like it needs to be reloaded or something.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 5, the PurchaseNewItems controller needs to tell its `parentViewController`'s `presentingViewController` to dismiss the modal view controller. (You can no longer refer to the presenter of a modal view as the modal view controller's `parentViewController`.)

Comment: That's what I needed. However when the presentingViewController becomes active it is a blank view (I think it's been pushed out of memory)

Comment: A view controller is not pushed out of memory while it presenting another view modally. Its view might be unloaded, but it will be loaded again when the view reappears. You'll need to think more about how this view is initialized, what its loadView, viewDidLoad, viewDidUnload, viewDid/will(dis)appear look like, in order to explain the problem.

Comment: the presentingviewcontroller is a tab in a tabbarcontroller. Could that have anything to do with it? There's nothing in the init method (that I added) viewWill appears calls a refreshList to self to refresh my tableview from an external DB. other than that no changes.

Comment: I'd have to see your particular situation and code, but I did say you need to think about viewWillAppear.

Comment: What should I be looking for?